# I am trying to share folders between linux and windows on vmware

Tags: linux, vmware

I am using Vmware(Linux) and HostPC(windows) I have wanted to share folder between them. specifically want to edit in windows environment and run in linux.

my shared folder location on linux is /home/kwon(user1)/sharedfolder/ I already installed vmware-tools and the sharedfolder is showing up after I run the command:
`/usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /home/kwon/sharedfolder -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other`

But, whenever I restart it, the folders dont show up anymore. I want them showing up anytime without running the command.. So, now, I run the command to see and use the folders whenever I restart it..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add fstab entries to auto mount the share when  the system boots up .

From the docs

Persistent Mounts
There are 2 ways to specify the Shared Folders mounts persistently in /etc/fstab
Below there are both samples /etc/fstab line to mount a FUSE vmhgfs export.

Method 1: Specifying the file system

Replace  with vmhgfs-fuse.
Replace  with the local file system on which the exported directory is mounted, which default replacement is to use /mnt/hgfs
Replace  with fuse.
Example:
vmhgfs-fuse    /mnt/hgfs    fuse    defaults,allow_other    0    0

Method 2: Specifying the remote server and share

:</remote/export> </local/directory>    
Replace  with the hostname .host the shared folders name of the host server exporting the hosts file system.
Replace </remote/export> with the path to the exported directory which defaults to/or you can use the /share-name-you-created.
Replace </local/directory> with the local file system on which the exported directory is mounted, which defaults to /mnt/hgfs.
Replace  with fuse.vmhgfs-fuse.
Example:
.host:/    /mnt/hgfs        fuse.vmhgfs-fuse    defaults,allow_other    0    0

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/60262